# Gitea under Configuration Management: Generated and Static Settings

Tags: configuration-management, gitea

I need to set up a Gitea server for an organization. The setup itself is easy, and I managed to bring up Gitea within an hour when installing it *manually*.

However, my organisation uses a configuration management tool, which handles secrets and configuration settings. So the idea is that I create `/etc/gitea/app.ini` using a configuration file template.

But when I run the Gitea setup, additional values are created, such as JWT tokens (`JWT_SECRET` in the `[oauth2]` section of the config file), which I clearly cannot make up  before Gitea is up and running.

So on one side, I need to pre-define the `app.ini`, on the other hand, I need Gitea to control `app.ini`. But when my provisioning script runs, it will overwrite those settings.

Is it possible to split up those two sets of settings over multiple configuration file: one to pre-define statically, and one to be managed by Gitea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the JWT has only a "not valid before" date and therefore doesn't need updates. So it works fine with a single config file.